# Is there any way to change the font-size of header in exported excel using ag-grid with angluar

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When we export the data displayed in a ag-grid we can export them using the built in export functionality. For the exported excel we need to change the font size of all cells including the header. there is a way to change the font size on the data cell values but not the cell headers.

Cell value font size can be edited by using excelStyles and providing the font: { size: "11"} in the JSON.

Does anyone know how we can change the font-size for the headers in the exported excel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use id `header` that will map the grid headers inside excelStyles.

> Headers are a special case, headers are exported to Excel as normal rows, so in order to allow you to style them you can provide an ExcelStyle with id and name "header". If you do so, the headers

```js
excelStyles: [
  {
      id: 'header',
      font: {size: 35}
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: The column and row titles still remain non-configurable right now, based on this thread,
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3676#issuecomment-788806156